# jQuery search in fields with a specific td class

Tags: jquery, ajax, search, field

My search currently searches through all the table fields - I would like it to only search the ones that have a td class of test.

I'm using

```
$('input#SearchBox').quicksearch('table#tablesorter-demo tbody tr');
```

This searches all the fields in the table, I have tried:

```
$('input#SearchBox').quicksearch('table#tablesorter-demo tbody tr td.test');
```

but this just stops the whole search from working.

I also tried:

```
'$('input#SearchBox').quicksearch('table#tablesorter-demo tbody tr', {'selector': 'td.test'})'
```

But this doesn't find anything.

Comment: Still not got this working then? Can you post the html for the table that you are trying to search?

Comment: do you need the list of td with "test" class?

Comment: @infernalbadger - unfortunately not! I had tried to reply to you i nthe previous topic but as I was not registered i could no longer reply. The table is generated from data in MySQL and obviously using PHP. Your jsfiddle did indeed work so im not sure why it doesnt comply with mine!

Comment: Do view source on your page and copy some of the table html into your answer. That might help us find your problem.

Comment: @infernalbadger its just the usual:
'<td class="firstname">Joe</td>
<td class="last_name">Bloggs</td>
<td class="mobile_telephone">01234567891</td>
<td class="date_of_birth">13/10/67</td>
<td class="test">one</td>'

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help

`$('#SearchBox').quicksearch('#tablesorter-demo tbody tr td .test');`

Comment: I think this alone will be enough. Since you are searching on a particular id